# Обход матрицы по спирали, начиная с центра. Содержимое массива не играет роли. C++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, матрицы

Необходимо реализовать алгоритм, обходящий матрицу 13*13 по спирали, начиная с центра. Решение представить на языке - C++. Алгоритм без вспомогательных библиотек с единственной точкой обращения к массиву, не основываясь на его содержание.

Подумал, что для решения задачи можно будет применить обход по спирали **массива**. Такой обход реализовать получилось. Язык - C++:

```
#define N 13
//...
int cc = 1;
int A[N];
for (int j = 1; j <= N; j++) {
    c = (j / 2) * ((j % 2) * 2 - 1);
    A[N / 2 + c] = cc++;
}
```

Выводится массив следующего содержания:`{12, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13}`

Казалось, что решение найдено. Вариант алгоритма для **матрицы**:

```
int A[N][N];

int ci = N / 2;
int cj = N / 2;

int cc = 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
{
    ci = (i / 2) * (1 - (i % 2) * 2);
    for (int j = 1; j <= N; j++)
    {
        cj = (j / 2) * ((j % 2) * 2 - 1);
        A[N / 2 + ci][N / 2 + cj] = cc++;
    }
}
```

Выдаёт не совсем то, что нужно в задаче:

```
{168, 166, 164, 162, 160, 158, 157, 159, 161, 163, 165, 167, 169}
{142, 140, 138, 136, 134, 132, 131, 133, 135, 137, 139, 141, 143}
{116, 114, 112, 110, 108, 106, 105, 107, 109, 111, 113, 115, 117}
{90, 88, 86, 84, 82, 80, 79, 81, 83, 85, 87, 89, 91}
{64, 62, 60, 58, 56, 54, 53, 55, 57, 59, 61, 63, 65}
{38, 36, 34, 32, 30, 28, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39}
{12, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13}
{25, 23, 21, 19, 17, 15, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26}
{51, 49, 47, 45, 43, 41, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 50, 52}
{77, 75, 73, 71, 69, 67, 66, 68, 70, 72, 74, 76, 78}
{103, 101, 99, 97, 95, 93, 92, 94, 96, 98, 100, 102, 104}
{129, 127, 125, 123, 121, 119, 118, 120, 122, 124, 126, 128, 130}
{155, 153, 151, 149, 147, 145, 144, 146, 148, 150, 152, 154, 156}
```

Алгоритмов в интернете не нашёл, что очень странно, задача кажется очень понятной. Возможно, нужен ещё один внешний цикл; нужно в двух циклах изменить конечные и начальные точки.

**P.S.** Алгоритм должен иметь обращение к массиву только в **единственном** месте кода: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NK3xM.jpg

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99672/discussion-on-question-by-egor-randomize-------).

Comment: @AK напрасно, потому что народ не понимает словий задачи

Comment: Модер удалил важный коммент, поэтому повторю: решение найдено, но оно не удовлетворяет условиям задачи. Пока не будет доказано существование алгоритма, удовлетворяющего условиям, галка будет у того, у кого она сейчас

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Простой обход массива по спирали, начиная с центра (C#)

```
var array = new int[13, 13];

for(int i=0; i<array.GetLength(0); i++)
    for(int j=0; j<array.GetLength(1); j++)     
        array[i, j] = i*13+j;   

int iInd = array.GetLength(0)/2;
int jInd = array.GetLength(0)/2;    

int iStep = 1;
int jStep = 1;

Console.Write(array[iInd,jInd] + " ");                  
for(int i=0; i<13; i++){
    for (int h = 0; h < i; h++) Console.Write(array[iInd, jInd += jStep] + " ");
    for (int v = 0; v < i; v++) Console.Write(array[iInd += iStep, jInd] + " ");
    jStep = -jStep;
    iStep = -iStep;     
}   
for (int h = 0; h < array.GetLength(0)-1; h++) 
   Console.Write(array[iInd, jInd += jStep] + " ");
```

Вывод

[image: ...]

**UPD**

Вариант с единой точкой доступа к массиву.

```
int len = 13;
var array = new int[len, len];

for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < len; j++)
        array[i, j] = i * len + j;

int iInd = len / 2;
int jInd = len / 2;

int iStep = 1;
int jStep = 1;

Func<int,int, int> getter = (i, j)=>array[i, j];

Console.Write(getter(iInd, jInd) + " ");
for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
{
    for (int h = 0; h < i; h++) Console.Write(getter(iInd, jInd += jStep) + " ");
    for (int v = 0; v < i; v++) Console.Write(getter(iInd += iStep, jInd) + " ");
    jStep = -jStep;
    iStep = -iStep;
}
for (int h = 0; h < len - 1; h++)
    Console.Write(getter(iInd, jInd += jStep) + " ");
```

Comment: Алгоритм должен иметь обращение к массиву только в единственном месте кода: https://imgur.com/a/D7qCZxl

Comment: @EgorRandomize обновил ответ.

Comment: Обращение к массиву так или иначе проходит в четырёх местах, в то время как необходимо только в одном месте. Не печатать первый элемент отдельно, не печатать последнюю строчку отдельно, и пр.