# Заполнение двумерного массива вихрем

Tags: c#, массивы

Имеется массив n*n, необходимо его заполнить вихрем, т.е. что бы в центре было максимальное значение, а в первой ячейке минимальное(слева на право шло заполнение). Правильно ли, что это является метод заполнения массива делением отрезка пополам?

Comment: немножечко подредактируете [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1032200/179763) и получите то, что вам нужно.

Comment: @tym32167, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System;

namespace helix_array
{
    class Program
    {
        const int N = 7;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n = 0;
            int[,] helix = new int[N, N];

            int x0 = 0;
            int xn = N - 1;
            int y0 = 0;
            int yn = N - 1;

            while (n < N * N)
            {
                for (int x = x0; x <= xn; x++)
                {
                    helix[y0, x] = ++n;
                }

                y0++;

                for (int y = y0; y <= yn; y++)
                {
                    helix[y, xn] = ++n;
                }

                xn--;

                for (int x = xn; x >= x0; x--)
                {
                    helix[yn, x] = ++n;
                }

                yn--;

                for (int y = yn; y >= y0; y--)
                {
                    helix[y, x0] = ++n;
                }

                x0++;
            }

            for (int y = 0; y < N; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < N; x++)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0}\t", helix[y, x]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

**Вывод**:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   
24  25  26  27  28  29  8   
23  40  41  42  43  30  9   
22  39  48  49  44  31  10  
21  38  47  46  45  32  11  
20  37  36  35  34  33  12  
19  18  17  16  15  14  13
```

[ideone](https://ideone.com/xFIuu3)

Comment: Думаю, стоит добавить какие то пояснения к коду и какие то результаты его работы.

Comment: Да он работает, и заполняет массив как нужно. Но вопрос следующий, является ли этот алгоритм, методом деления отрезка пополам?

Comment: @Valera если верить википедии, то нет, этот метод для других целей. `Метод бисекции или метод деления отрезка пополам — простейший численный метод для решения нелинейных уравнений вида f(x)=0`.