# Помогите скорректировать код для использования разных переменных столбцов и строк

Tags: c#

Написал код, который заполняет массив порядковыми числами по спирали, начиная с `array[0,0]` которому дается значение 1.

Но он работает только при условии, что кол-во столбцов и строк равны. не пойму как изменить, чтобы работало с разными переменными строк и столбцов (например 3 строки, 4 столбца)

```cs
int[,] GetSpiral2(int[,] result)
{
    int temp = 1;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while (temp <= result.GetLength(0) * result.GetLength(1))
    {
        result[i, j] = temp;
        temp++;
        if (i <= j + 1 && i + j < result.GetLength(1) - 1)
            j++;
       else if (i < j && i + j >= result.GetLength(0) - 1)
            i++;
       else if (i >= j && i + j > result.GetLength(1) - 1)
            j--;
       else
            i--;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Ну вот [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1032200/179763) как из центра по спирали пройти в края, вам видимо надо то же самое, только в обратном направлении.

Comment: Спасибо, но к сожалению там код тоже с квадратным массивом(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По большому счету, если представить двумерную матрицу как вложенные прямоугольники, то вам надо просто обойти каждый прямоугольник по контуру.

Например, если матрица 5х4

```
00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00
```

то это просто вложенные пямоугольники 5х4 и 3х2, пример:

```
xx xx xx xx
xx yy yy xx
xx yy yy xx
xx yy yy xx
xx xx xx xx
```

далее, зная ширину, высоту и верхний левый угол, мы пройдем сначала внешнмй пямоугольник, потом повторим тот же самый алгоритм для внутреннего

```
01 02 03 04
14 yy yy 05
13 yy yy 06
12 yy yy 07
11 10 09 08
```

Внутренний

```
01 02 03 04
14 15 16 05
13 20 17 06
12 19 18 07
11 10 09 08
```

Ну теперь дело за малым, построим функцию, которая так проходит по матрице

```cs
private void SpiralFill(int[,] array)
{
    var total = array.GetLength(0) * array.GetLength(1);
    var curr = 1;

    int xPos = 0;
    int yPos = 0;

    int h = array.GetLength(0);
    int w = array.GetLength(1);

    while (total >= curr)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < w; i++)
            array[xPos, yPos + i] = curr++;

        for (int i = 1; i < h; i++)
            array[xPos + i, yPos + w - 1] = curr++;

        for (int i = 1; i < w && curr <= total; i++)
            array[xPos + h - 1, (yPos + w - 1) - i] = curr++;

        for (int i = 1; i < h - 1 && curr <= total; i++)
            array[(xPos + h - 1) - i, yPos] = curr++;
        xPos++;
        yPos++;
        h -= 2;
        w -= 2;
    }
}
```

Естесственно, мы 2 раза по одним и тем же ячейкам не ходим, потому мы оставновимся, когда пройдем все ячейки матрицы.

Ну, для проверки, накатаем функцию вывода матрицы на печать

```cs
private void Print(int[,] array)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
            Console.Write($"{array[i, j]:00} ");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Ну и проверка

```cs
var array = new int[10, 5];
SpiralFill(array);
Print(array);

Console.WriteLine();

array = new int[5, 10];
SpiralFill(array);
Print(array);
```

Вывод

```
01 02 03 04 05 
26 27 28 29 06 
25 44 45 30 07 
24 43 46 31 08 
23 42 47 32 09 
22 41 48 33 10 
21 40 49 34 11 
20 39 50 35 12 
19 38 37 36 13 
18 17 16 15 14 

01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 
26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 11 
25 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 35 12 
24 43 42 41 40 39 38 37 36 13 
23 22 21 20 19 18 17 16 15 14
```

Comment: Спасибо!!!! Теперь стало более понятно, как такие вещи можно решить :)